# Change div to a href link on mouseover and click using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

A div with a data url attribute must be replaced by a link. The link must get the data-url attribute from the div. However, this should only happen with a mouseover or a click.

So this div:

```
<div class="thelink" data-url="https://www.example.com">The Title</div>
```

should become to this on mouseover or a click

```
<a href="https://www.example.com">The Title</a>
```

I tried something like this:

```
<script>

$(".thelink").on('click mouseover', function(){

replaceWith("<a href=\"here data-url\">The Title</a>");

});
```

Is this possible? Thank you very much for your time and effort.

Comment: Basically yes, but you need to use `$(this).replaceWith($('<a>').text($(this).text()).attr("href", $(this).data("url")));`.

Comment: I tried it but the link keeps after mouseover. thank you

Comment: Just add a similar event for `mouseout` that turns it back. This entire thing seems weird though; why do you want to do this in the first place? Why not have an `<a>` from the start?

Comment: it has to do with affiliate links. What is with the click in the function? Do you mean something like this? $(".thelink").on('click mouseover', function(){

//replaceWith("<a href=\"here data-url\">The Link</a>");

$(this).replaceWith($('<a>').text($(this).text()).attr("href", $(this).data("url")));

});

$(".thelink").on('click mouseout', function(){

//replaceWith("<a href=\"here data-url\">The Link</a>");

$(this).replaceWith($('<div>').text($(this).text()).attr("data-url", $(this).data("url")));

});

Comment: I think this is to long. Is there no better way to remove the mouseover?

Comment: I'm testing this and the problem is that a new element is created under the mouse, so adding the `mouseout` event is actually not that simple. Again, what is the actual goal here? Because it is possible to just make the `<div>` act like an `<a>`.

Comment: I know but the browser has to display in the status bar the URL and the browser react only with a "a href". When its not that simple, a append instead of replace is also possible

Comment: Here's my version: https://jsfiddle.net/u23b58nz/

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You shouldn't replace elements like that, since you can just remove the `href` attribute to disable the link. And also, what about people without a mouse?

Comment: @ChrisG thank you very much. Works perfekt. Which one should I use, yours or AlwaysHelping? Which one is safer?   D. Pardal Is has to do with bots and crawling. I dont want, that the bots see the url in the a href.

Comment: Why  not use an <a> tag with a href linking to your pages and just change the href on mouseover?

Comment: @Andyba I dont want the bots crawl the url.

Comment: You can link to the current page or not use any href attribute at all.
Also from your question it is not clear that you want to change back to the div on mouseout.

Comment: _“I dont want, that the bots see the url in the a href”_ - a lot of bots are probably not even that sophisticated, that they do actual DOM parsing … anything that just goes over your HTML with a regular expression to find anything resembling a URL, would still find this all the same.

Comment: @CBroe google is parsing the DOM but I dont think that google do a mouseover on every URL?

Comment: No one needs to do any mouseovers to realize that the content of `data-url="https://www.example.com"` is a URL.

Comment: and when I change data-url to data-id ?

Comment: See, that's why I asked what your actual goal is. You do not actually want to replace <div>s with <a>s, you want to *hide links from a crawler*. I should've insisted on my suspicion that this is an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on dynamically added element and use `mouseover` to add an `a` and on `mouseout` it will add the `div` back again.

We also need to use a `class` on our `a` `href` element so that we can use the same use to on `mouseout` to bring back the original `div`

**Demo**

```js
//Mouse over function
$(document).on('mouseover click', '.thelink', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<a class="newLink">').text($(this).text()).attr("href", $(this).data("url")));
});

//Mouse out function
$(document).on('mouseout click', '.newLink', function() {
  $(this).replaceWith($('<div class="thelink">').text($(this).text()).attr("data-url", $(this).attr("href")));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="thelink" data-url="https://www.example.com">The Title</div>
```

Comment: @LarsVegas Glad to hear :) Would you mind accepting the answer please and upvote ?

Comment: yes, I will do. What do you think about the solution from chris?

Comment: @LarsVegas See the thing is both code works fine. Chris code is using more functions like `.append` `.parent`. `.find` `.length` - I could have provided solution like Chris but i thought it would be good to keep the solution based on your current code so there not much changing and you will easily understand as well.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any advantage on one of them by using a smartphone and mouseover?

Comment: @LarsVegas Nope there is no advantage. Both will work the same way in a smartphone specifically.

Comment: great. Have a nice day and thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```
$(".thelink").on('click mouseover', function(){
   let dataURL = $(this).data('url');
   $(this).replaceWith(`<a href="${dataURL}">The Title</a>`);
});
```

But if you need to simply open a url when clicking on a div you can do it like this:

```
$(".thelink").on('click', function(){
   window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
});
```

Comment: Why -1. At least explain in comments so that people learn from my mistakes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I have not give you an downvote.

Comment: @Andyba Its not my down-vote. But as you see this was not what OP needed and asked in the question (comments as well). Question is requesting something else to what you have answered with. Thanks :)

Comment: Actually i disagree, he asked: 
"A div with a data url attribute must be replaced by a link. The link must get the data-url attribute from the div. However, this should only happen with a mouseover or a click."

Nowhere in the question is he asking how to change back to a div on mouseout.
And for his purpose - bots not seeing the links -  this is not really necessary.

Comment: TBH it's a bad question without clarity, asking an XY problem.  This solves both the question *as asked* and provides an additional solution to the *actual* problem.  OP has come up with a bad solution for their XY problem and even then only *half-asked* about that.

Comment: I retracted my downvote because it turns out that this is the actual answer (the 2nd snippet). Add some hover CSS and you have your fully-fledged pseudo <a>.